# How to de-crypt password that i've hashed with Bcrypt (for display purposes)?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, bcrypt

I'm creating an application that allows users to log with username/password combo.
I have an Administrator account that creates those users, and i hash the passwords as i store them in the mySQL DB.
However, if a user forgets his/her password, i want to be able to see it in it's un-hashed state in this Administrator account and be able to change it.
Is this possible and how one goes about this ?

The technologies that i'm using are Laravel/Vue/mySQL/Bcrypt.

Comment: It's not possible. It's one way only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bcrypt is hashing algorithm, and not a encryption one. Meaning it is not reversible.

> Bcrypt like any other salted hash method use the salt to avoid that the same password hashes to the same string. It is doing that by initially generating the salt randomly and then hashing password and salt. This can only be verified if the same salt is used when verifying. This is why the salt is saved together with the hash.
>
> Bcrypt like any other iterated hash method can not directly be inverted, but you can try all possible passwords to see if they hash to the same result. In case of salted methods you cannot precompute this, because you have to try with the actual salt (as described above).

If you seek to have password that can be de-encrypted, you might want to consider an encryption algorithm rather than a hashing one, or you could take a look at Laravel's own method `encrypt()`, although this would require you to rewrite the authentification methods on your application, and might be considered less secure.

More here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/encryption

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.

Hashing is a one-way mathematical operation and it cannot be un-done. You can only create a new hash and compare the two.

Comment: Oh... Okay, it appears that i might have to do some more digging on the matter or maybe change my approach entirely. Thanks for the feedback!